# Получение кода символа

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{

  printf("%d",(int)'А');
}
```

По идее, программа должна вывести код 'А'(кириллица), т.е. 192, но почему-то выводит -64.

Comment: `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип `char` может вести себя либо как тип `signed char` либо как тип `unsigned char` в зависимости от установленных опций компилятора.

В вашем случае тип `char` ведет себя как тип `signed char`.

Для типа `signed char` максимальное положительное значение равно `127` или в шестнадцатиричной форме `0x7F`.

Если хотите получить положительное значения кода, то напишите

```
printf("%d",(unsigned char)'А');
```

При этом русская буква не должна быть представлена как многобайтная константа.